# Find multiple object values in array

Tags: javascript

This is my object:

```
function Plane (x,z) {  
    this.x = x;
    this.z = z;
}

var plane = new Plane(0,50000);
```

I have an array with these objects:

```
planesArray.push(plane);
```

I have a point object:

```
function Point (x,z) {  
    this.x = x;
    this.z = z;
}

var point = new Point(0,-50000);
```

I need to check if in `planesArray` exist an object with the specific point, so to check if the values x and y of the point are equal to any of the planes in the array and, if NOT, to perform an action.

I am still a novice, I apologize if this question sounds dumb.

Comment: Now, is there a nice way do do the same but with 6 (or more) points, without repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array and return a boolean indicating whether or not there was found a `Point` object with those attributes. This example uses the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to perform this operation.

```
var found = planesArray.some(function(plane) {
    return plane.x === x && plane.y === y;
});

if (found) {

}
```

**Update**: Here is the same code as a function.

```
function found(list, x, y) {
    return list.some(function(plane) {
        return plane.x === x && plane.y === y;
    });
}
```

Comment: For existence, `.some` is enough. Also, you need `===`.

Comment: @pimvdb Thanks. I will incorporate that into my answer.

Comment: Just keep in mind, `Array.prototype.some` is not compatible with IE8 and under - http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: The only answer given that didn't actually work across all browsers, and it was the answer that was accepted. Um...

Comment: @wxactly Have you read the About page: *Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.* I realize this isn't cross browser, but if it's a viable and helpful solution to the OP then I see no reason to withhold my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand that. And clearly, your answer is the most elegant here, in terms of code... I just hope you're right when you say, "it worked for the person who asked." I was trying to emphasize the warning given by @osahyoun.

Comment: Actually I liked the clean code and I'm using webgl so I don't really care about ie8.

Comment: @user1356948 I don't understand the question..what are you asking?

Comment: I mean, now I should repeat the code for each point to check, I was wondering if there's a clean way to do it

Comment: @user1356948 Oh that's simple: just make `found` a function with arguments. I'll try tk make an edit showing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var point = new Point(0,-50000);
for(var i = 0; i < planesArray.length; i++) {
    var plane = planesArray[i];
    if(plane.x != point.x || plane.z != point.z) {
        //perform action
        //break; //optional, depending on whether you want to perform the action for all planes, or just one
    }
}
```